# Send form-data in wp_remote_post

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, multipartform-data

I have this `curl` request, which works:

```sh
curl -X POST "https://peyk.uk/api/v1/get-auth-token"
     -F "client_id=xxxxx"
     -F "client_secret=xxxx"
```

But when trying to reproduce with `wp_remote_post`, I keep getting a code 0 response, which is not helpful at all.

I have tried a lot of different combinations, but currently my request looks like the below:

```php
$body = json_encode(array(
  'client_id' => $this->settings['client_id'],
  'client_secret' => $this->settings['client_secret']
));

$result = wp_remote_post('https://peyk.uk/api/v1/get-auth-token', array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'),
  'body'=> array('formdata' => $body)
));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending body in JSON format, while your server expects it encoded like form fields.  Type this:

```php
$result = wp_remote_post('https://peyk.uk/api/v1/get-auth-token', array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'),
  'body' => array(
    'client_id' => $this->settings['client_id'],
    'client_secret' => $this->settings['client_secret']
  )
));
```

See [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/#user-contributed-notes) for details.